# WebView intent Facebook and Instagram

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, social-networking

I have WebView. On the site i click Social button(Facebook,Twitter, VK, OK, Instagram, Telegram). Work is VK, Twitter, YouTube and Telegram.  When I click this social button, I need to launch the application (if it is installed on my phone) But it starts only in WebView

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Intent to launch the installed apps. Pass the package name to launch the application.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```